# Request for google Homepage using http request xcode - objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

The following is the line of code that I have used for http request. On running the simulator I only get the "connecting as displayed" .. can someone help me with the right code so as to display the google homepage. thanks.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:www.google.com"] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 15.0];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate:self];

    if(connection){
        //connect
        label.text = @"connecting .....";

    }else{
        //error

    }
}


-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection *)conenction didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    response =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}


-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    connection = nil;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could just use a `UIWebView` to load the page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
   NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
```

Comment: The link you've provided is dead.  Mind reexplaining your answer?